# How to know if UnifiedNativeAd is NativeAppInstallAd or NativeContentAd?

Tags: android, admob, native-ads, unifiednativeadview

I am using [UnifiedNativeAd](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/formats/UnifiedNativeAd) to display native ad. How can I know if it's [NativeAppInstallAd](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/formats/NativeAppInstallAd) or [NativeContentAd](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/formats/NativeContentAd)?

As per [AdMob native ads policy compliance checklist](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6240814?hl=en&ref_topic=7384666), `NativeAppInstallAd` should always display Call To Action button while `NativeContentAd` doesn't need to show it (and indeed I don't show it due to my design of the native ad).

Answer (score 0):

Use `UnifiedNativeAdView adView` as layout root of native ad, you can judge from some getter of `UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd` and inject the value:

```
    if (nativeAd.getStore() == null) adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);              
    else {
        adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((TextView) adView.getStoreView()).setText(nativeAd.getStore());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getStarRating() == null) adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else {
        ((RatingBar) adView.getStarRatingView()).setRating(nativeAd.getStarRating().floatValue());
        adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    VideoController vc = nativeAd.getVideoController();
    if (vc.hasVideoContent()) { Log.d("TAG", "has video"); }
```

The code above is a part of google admob example project:  [googleads /
googleads-mobile-android-examples](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples), you could clone it and reset to earlier commit, it would really help.